# LDA implementaion in pymc3

Tags: python, pymc, latent-dirichlet-alloc

I am implementing LDA with pymc3 using the referred code for pymc from the post

[Latent Dirichlet Allocation in PyMC](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/104771/latent-dirichlet-allocation-in-pymc/120456#120456)

I am trying to use it for pymc3 bt having problems defining

`w`

```
import numpy as np
import pymc3 as pm, theano, theano.tensor as t

K = 2 # number of topics
V = 4 # number of words
D = 3 # number of documents

data = np.array([[1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0]])

alpha = np.ones(K)
beta = np.ones(V)
model = pm.Model()
Wd = [len(doc) for doc in data]
(D, W) = data.shape

pi = []
def dist_over_words(z,phi):
#    Phi = theano.shared(np.array(phi))
  #  print(phi[1])

    for d in range(D):
        for i in range(W):
            zi = z[d][i]
            pi.append(phi[zi])

with model: 
    theta = [pm.Dirichlet("pthetax_%s" % i, a=alpha, shape=K) for i in range(D)]
    phi =[pm.Dirichlet("pphix_%s" % k, a=beta,shape=V) for k in range(K)]


    z = [pm.Categorical('zx_%i' % d, 
                         p = theta[d], 
                         shape=Wd[d])
                      for d in range(D)]

    w = pm.Categorical("wx_d_i",p = dist_over_words(z,phi), observed = data)

with model:    
    step1 = pm.Metroplolis(vars = [theta,phi,z,w])
    tr = step1.sample(1000,step = [step1])

pm.plots.traceplot(tr, ['theta', 'phi', 'z','w']);
```

I am getting the error :

> pi.append(phi[zi])
>
> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not TensorVariable

How can I model for `w` since `phi` is a list and `z[d][i]` will always be a tensor?

Help much appreciated